# XTEXT: Controlling when whitespace is allowed

Tags: whitespace, dsl, xtext

I have a custom scripting language, that I am attempting to use XTEXT for syntax checking.  It boils down to single line commands in the format

```
COMMAND:PARAMETERS
```

For the most part, xtext is working great.  The only problem I have currently run into is how to handle wanted (or unwanted) white spaces.  The language cannot have a space to begin a line, and there cannot be a space following the colon.  As well, I need to allow white space in the parameters, as it could be a string of text, or something similar.

I have used a datatype to allow white space in the parameter:

```
UNQUOTED_STRING:
    (ID | INT | WS | '.' )+
;
```

This works, but has the side effect of allowing spaces throughout the line.

Does anyone know a way to limit where white spaces are allowed?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disallow whitespace globally for your grammar by using an empty set of hidden tokens, e.g.

```
grammar org.xyz.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals hidden()
```

Then you can enable it at specific rules, e.g.

```
XParameter hidden(WS):
    'x' '=' value=ID
;
```

Note that this would allow linebreaks as well. If you don't want that you can either pass a custom terminal rule or overwrite the default `WS`rule.

Here is a more complete example (not perfect):

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals hidden()

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

Model:
    (commands+=Command '\r'? '\n')+
;

Command:
    SampleCommand
;

SampleCommand:
    command='get' ':' parameter=Parameter 
;

Parameter:
    '{' x=XParameter '}'
;

XParameter hidden(WS):
    'x' '=' value=ID
;
```

This will parse commands such as:

```
get:{x=TEST}
get:{ x =  TEST}
```

But will reject:

```
 get:{x=TEST}
get: {x=TEST}
```

Hope that gives you an idea. You can also do this the other way around by limiting the whitespace only for certain rules, e.g.

```
CommandList hidden():
    (commands+=Command '\r'? '\n')+
;
```

If that works better for your grammar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74100643/xtext-how-to-ignore-string-in-regex  can check this look similar to this